# Heap corrupted and strange breakpoint in Runge Kutta diff eq solver

Tags: c++, pointers, breakpoints, runge-kutta

I'm trying to implement Runga Kutta method for solving the Lorenz differential equation system.
At some point, the program always stops at a breakpoint which I can't see, and then throws an error about heap corruption.
Something must be wrong with the way I use the pointers, but I have no idea what's not working well.
Here's my code:// Runge_Kutta.cpp : This file contains the 'main' function. Program execution begins and ends there.

````
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
const int dimension=3;
double* F = new double(3);
double p1 = 10;
double p2 = 28;
double p3 = 8.0 / 3.0;
double* K1 = new double(3);
double* K2 = new double(3);
double* K3 = new double(3);
double* K4 = new double(3);
double* X = new double(3);
double* t = new double(3);
double a = 0;
double b = 100;
const int N = 1000;
//double * x=new double[N];

double dt = (b - a) / N;

void f(double *F,double *x, double *t)
{   
    double dx1 = p1 * (x[1] - x[0]);
    double dx2 = x[0] * (p2 - x[2]) - x[1];
    double dx3 = x[0] * x[1] - p3 * x[2];
    //cout << "dx-ek: " << dx1 << " " << dx2 << " " << dx3 << "\n";
    F[0] = dx1;
    F[1] = dx2;
    F[2] = dx3;
}

double* RK4(double* x, double *t, double dt)
{
    f(K1, x, t);
    //cout << "K1: " << K1[0] << " " << K1[1] << " " << K1[2] << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        X[i] = x[i] + dt * K1[i] * 0.5;
    }
    f(K2, X, t);
    //cout << "K2: " << K2[0] << " " << K2[1] << " " << K2[2] << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        X[i] = x[i] + dt * K2[i] * 0.5;
    }
    f(K3, X, t);
    //cout << "K3: " << K3[0] << " " << K3[1] << " " << K3[2] << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        X[i] = x[i] + dt * K2[i] * 0.5;
    }
    f(K4, X, t);
    //cout << "K4: " << K4[0] << " " << K4[1] << " " << K4[2] << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        //cout << "Ennek nem kéne 0-nak lennie: " << K1[i] * 0.1666666 + K2[i] * 0.33333333 + K3[i] * 0.3333333 + K4[i] * 0.1666666 << '\n';
        x[i] = x[i] + dt * (K1[i] * 0.1666666 + K2[i] * 0.33333333 + K3[i] * 0.3333333 + K4[i] * 0.1666666);
        //cout << "Return előtt előtt: " << x[0] << " " << x[1] << " " << x[2] << "\n";
    }
    //cout << "Return előtt: " << x[0] << " " << x[1] << " " << x[2] << "\n";
    return x;

    
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Let's start!";
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("solution.csv");
    double* x = new double(3);
   /*
    for(int z=0;z<dimension;z++)
    {
        //cout << "WHat the heck?";
        x[z]= 0;
    }
    */
    x[0] = -5.0;
    x[1] = 0.0;
    x[2] = 0.0;
    auto start=std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
        RK4(x, t, dt);
        //cout << j << "\n";
        //cout << "Return után  "<< x[0] << " " <<x[1]<<" "<<x[2]<<"    it: "<<j << "\n";
        //cout << "\n";
        
        for (int u = 0; u < dimension; u++)
        {
            myfile << x[u];
            if (u <= dimension - 2) myfile << ",";
            else myfile << "\n";
        }
        

    }
    auto elapsed = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()-start;
    long long microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(elapsed).count();
    cout << "Simulation time: " << microseconds << " microsec" << endl << endl;
    myfile.close();```
````

Comment: It doesn't crash for me, but there are several warnings about variable shadowing and one about an unused parameter. You might look at cleaning those up. What compiler are you using and how are you compiling this?

Comment: Run in the debugger, wait until he program crashes, then go up the stack until the debugger is showing a line from your code. What is that line? Have the debugger print the values of the relevant variables. Are they what you expect them to be?

Comment: `new double(3);` dynamically allocates one `double` initialized to `3`.

Comment: This program needs exactly zero uses of `new`. Why are you dynamically allocating arrays of 3 doubles? This makes no sense. If you need an array of 3 elements, declare one, e.g. `double x[3];` Also bear in mind that overuse of global variables (those outside of functions) is usually a poor programming style.

Comment: You did not compute the `X` for `K4` correctly, it is still the copy of the `X` for `K3`. In the assembling of the step, you reduce the accuracy to about single precision due to the explicit constants. It would be better to define constants `ONETHIRD` and `ONESIXTH` or `dt_by_6` if you want to avoid repeated division by 6.